# Batch, Symbolic Link created, but not all folders/files are linked

Tags: batch-file, symlink

I have this structure:

`K:\private\test\files`

`K:\
   private
      test
         files
         test.txt`

creating symbolic link to:

`C:Users\username\Documents`

as:

`mklink /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Test "K:\"`

Now, the symbolic link is created, but not fully. The `Test` folder is created, `private` folder can be opened, but `test` folder can't be opened. I get this error:

> Location is not available.
>
> C:\Users\username\Documents\Test\private\test is unavailable. If the
>   location is on this PC, make sure the device or drive is connected or
>   the disc is inserted, and then try again. If the location is on a
>   network, maker sure you're connected to the network or Internet, and
>   then try again. If the location still can't be found, it might have
>   been moved or deleted.

How can I create the symbolic link so that everything is linked. Can it be the issue with the `test.txt` inside `test` folder?